# CSS to be applied to DIV contents

Tags: css

I have a DIV like the following:

```
  <td>  
    <DIV>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // link to some js
    </script>
    </DIV>
  </td>
```

The .js renders the latest article abstract inside the div. However it renders it in Calibri 10px.

I want that any content inside the DIV should be rendered as Verdana 10px. I am using a 3rd party .js so have no control over it. How to I force the DIV to render the content the way I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the elements the Javascript is adding have their own style declarations, then you will need to use more Javascript to override them.

Otherwise, You should be able to give your div a class, apply your styles to that class, then they should propagate through to any contents inside.

e.g.

css:

```
.myClass {
  font-family: Verdana; 
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

html:

```
  <td>  
    <div class="myClass">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // link to some js
    </script>
    </div>
  </td>
```

If that doesn't work, change the CSS to this:

```
.myClass * {
  font-family: Verdana; 
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried it without any effect! I think the js is adding its own style definitions..How can I override it?

Comment: Unfortunately CSS inheritance means you have to use Javascript to remove the style declarations of the elements in your div

Answer (score 2):

If the javascript only puts content and no style, you could do this:

```
  <td>  
    <DIV style='font-family: Verdana; font-size: 10px;'>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // link to some js
    </script>
    </DIV>
  </td>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried it without any effect! I think the js is adding its own style definitions..How can I override it?

Comment: You need to 1) extract content generated by javascript, and 2) display this content inside your div. To do the task you could (or should) use some library like jquery.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check what elements the javascript generates. Use firebug in FireFox or "Inspect element" in Chrome.

When you know the element, specify something like this in your stylesheet.

```
body table tr td div elementOrClassNameThatYouFound {
  font: verdana 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also try something in your CSS like:

```
.myClass {
    font-family: Verdana !important;
    font-size: 10px !important;
}
```